# How to find the index of a praticular word in the whole sentence

Tags: javascript

i want to find a text named "footer= XXX" in a text document and replace the XXX with my own value. The problem here is that this footer value repeats in lot of areas in the document with different values assigned to it. Any idea of how to do it?

Comment: can you elaborate on what should be included and what excluded when searching for this pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
str.replace(/footer=(.*?)\s/g, 'footer=whatever');
```

[See it on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DrbX4/).

You didn't mention what the end delimiter is, so I used white space. You may want to use a word boundary (`\b`).